# How to detect mouse events over option drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery and need to be able to detect whether a user has their mouse over an option of a drop down menu. It is able to detect whether it is over other elements, but not "option".

My HTML is a simple drop down menu:

```
<select name="menu">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

My JavaScript is:

```
$("option").mouseenter(function() {
    console.log("Mouse has touched option");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with native select tag.

You can achieve that while using some jquery dropdown such as:

https://select2.org/

Answer (score 0):

very interesting question,but you **can't** do this, but also, you can create custom dropdown menu, with custom HTML and CSS and trigger custom `events` on it, see also: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp)